# EN55032 Conducted Emissions - 40cm From Vertical Reference Ground Plane

Tags: emc, ground-plane, ce, emissions

I've always wondered why we need to position the EUT 40cm from the metallic wall for conducted emissions testing. Does it have something to do with the EUT capacitively coupling the higher end of the frequencies between 150kHz-30MHz to the wall and then the LISN picks up that noise as part of the measurement?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome! Unfortunately, idle(ish?) curiosity questions like this, often don't have a convenient or satisfying answer. While it is likely there are people who know the exact reason, it is also likely that only very few do, i.e. those who served on the committee that originally wrote the standard.  Perhaps you can get lucky and one such person sees this post and answers; more likely, you'll get speculation -- or even worse, opinion.  As such, you're probably as well off just coming up with some guesses yourself, and being satisfied with that. Best wishes!

Comment: Is the table height of 0.8m for ergonomics??

Comment: @Kartman, I don't even know the reasoning for the 0.8m either